# Chosing the right collider for complex objects - unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, collider

Hi I have an object like this(a quarter circle with some thickness) how should I draw the best fitting collider around it?
I tried custom, composite collider but don't know how to work with them.
Also polygon collider gets kind of messy.

Answer (score 0):

Unity has a component for this - *Mesh Collider*.

"The benefit of this is that you can make the shape of the Collider exactly the same as the shape of the visible Mesh for the GameObject, which creates more precise and authentic collisions. However, this precision comes with a higher processing overhead than collisions involving primitive colliders (such as Sphere, Box, and Capsule), so it is best to use Mesh Colliders sparingly."
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html